# Java StackOverflowError when I try to use Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I Wanted to print the 2 statements from the payFees class while the getReceipt class waits for the execution of the payFees class and vice versa with the getReceipt class and admissionCompleted class using Multithreading

It shows the java.lang.StackOverflowError.
But when I try to Initalise all the objects of these classes and call the start() and join(), It works perfectly.

Please Help.

```
package codes;

class payFees extends Thread 
{   
    public payFees()
    {   
        this.start();
        getReceipt g= new getReceipt();
        g.start();
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Withdraw Amount");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Fees Paid");
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class getReceipt extends Thread 
{
    payFees p=new payFees();
    
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            p.join();
            System.out.println("Ask for Receipt");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Receipt collected");
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            
        }
    }
}

class admissionCompleted extends Thread 
{   
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {   
        new payFees();
        getReceipt g=new getReceipt();
            
        try
        {   
            g.join();
            System.out.println("Wait for confirmation");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Successfully completed admission process");
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't define the thread to stop anytime. Also the class names start with Capital Letters as of Java Best Practices

Comment: Don't extend `Thread`.  Implementing `Runnable` is better.  Or anonymous subclasses of `Runnable` or lambdas.

Comment: You have a circular dependency so you are creating objects until you run out of memory. Your `main` will create a `payFees` and a `getReceipt` object. The `payFees` will then again create a `getReceipt` object and the `getReceipt` will create a new `payFees`. And so on...

Comment: how and where should I define  that?@Anchit

Comment: What changes should I make in my code@maloomeister

Comment: Depends on how many times you wanna print. Basic example is using a for loop.
Refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm . Here the thread runs within the for-loop only.